# Flutter Dio : How to Upload Image?

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

### I'm trying on Postman. And it works

[image: Postman]
I want upload some image to rest-api using Package **DIO Package** ,
I'm new for this package (i'm use this package just for CRUD operation) and i'm got problem when upload image operation. 
i'm already reading documentation and nothing see for upload images. I'm try this code(ref on documentation) and got some error :

```
error:FileSystemException
message :"Cannot retrieve length of file"
OSError (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
"File: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.mosque/files/Pictures/scaled_IMG_20190815_183541.jpg'"
Type (FileSystemException)
message:FileSystemException: Cannot retrieve length of file, path = 'File: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.mosque/files/Pictures/scaled_IMG_20190815_183541.jpg'' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
DioErrorType (DioErrorType.DEFAULT)
name:"DioErrorType.DEFAULT"
```

#### Api.dart

```
Future uploadImage({dynamic data,Options options}) async{
      Response apiRespon =  await dio.post('$baseURL/mahasiswa/upload/',data: data,options: options);
      if(apiRespon.statusCode== 201){
        return apiRespon.statusCode==201;
      }else{
        print('errr');
        return null;
      }
}
```

#### View.dart

```
void uploadImage() async {
    FormData formData = FormData.from({
      "name_image": _txtNameImage.text,
      "image": UploadFileInfo(File("$_image"), "image.jpg")
    });
    bool upload =
        await api.uploadImage(data: formData, options: CrudComponent.options);
    upload ? print('success') : print('fail');
  }
```

> **_image** is type FILE

I hope who expert with this package can help me with this code and suggest me for upload images.
Thanks.

#### Full View.dart Code

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:mosque/api/api_mosque.dart';

class UploadImage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UploadImageState createState() => _UploadImageState();
}

class _UploadImageState extends State<UploadImage> {
  ApiHelper api = ApiHelper();
  File _image;
  TextEditingController _txtNameImage = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_left),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.file_upload),
            onPressed: () {
              uploadImage();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: _formUpload(),
    );
  }

  Widget _formUpload() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            controller: _txtNameImage,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Nama Image"),
            maxLength: 9,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 50.0,
          ),
          Container(
            child: _image == null
                ? Text('No Images Selected')
                : Image.file(_image),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 50.0,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.camera),
                onPressed: () => getImageCamera(),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 50.0,
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.image),
                onPressed: () => getImageGallery(),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void uploadImage() async {
    FormData formData = FormData.from({
      "name_image": _txtNameImage.text,
      "image": UploadFileInfo(File("$_image"), "image.jpg")
    });
    bool upload =
        await api.uploadImage(data: formData, options: CrudComponent.options);
    upload ? print('success') : print('fail');
  }

  getImageGallery() async {
    var imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      _image = imageFile;
    });
  }

  getImageCamera() async {
    var imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      _image = imageFile;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

In **Dio latest version**, `UploadFileInfo` method has been replaced by `MultipartFile` class. And here the way how to use to post image, video or any file:

```
Future<String> uploadImage(File file) async {
    String fileName = file.path.split('/').last;
    FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
        "file":
            await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path, filename:fileName),
    });
    response = await dio.post("/info", data: formData);
    return response.data['id'];
}
```

Comment: On single image upload its work, but how to upload multiple images from List<File> using FormData ?, please possible help about this. thank you

Comment: using a loop man!
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
 await uploadImage(file);
}

Comment: yes, i solve this with formdata mapentry under list.foreach loop.

Comment: FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
      "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path,
          filename: fileName,contentType: MediaType.parse("image/png")),
    });                                                                                                                               after adding contentType:MediaType.parse('image/png');  my image posted on server  try this if any one have porblem

Comment: Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [400]

Comment: `using a loop man!` This is usually a bad idea, if your backend fails half way through for some reason you will have inconsistent / partially saved data.  Better to let your api do an "all or nothing" and let your consuming app know about it in a response.

Comment: I keep getting error 415, Unsupported MediaType of application/octet-stream, any work around?

Comment: For web:   
 FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
        "file":
            await MultipartFile.fromBytes(imageBytes, filename:fileName),
    });

Answer (score 44):

Even this question is asked a while ago, I believe the main issue is the `size` of image especially with `Laravel`.[Flutter Image Picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) library offers some functionalities to reduce the size of Image, I solved it with bellow steps:

1. Create a method to get the Image, I am using `Camera` to Capture the photo

   ```
   Future getImage() async {
        File _image;
        final picker = ImagePicker(); 

       var _pickedFile = await picker.getImage(
       source: ImageSource.camera,
       imageQuality: 50, // <- Reduce Image quality
       maxHeight: 500,  // <- reduce the image size
       maxWidth: 500);

      _image = _pickedFile.path;


     _upload(_image);

   }
   ```
2. Create `_upload` method to upload the photo, I am using `Dio` package [Dio Package](https://pub.dev/packages/dio#request-options)

   ```
   void _upload(File file) async {
      String fileName = file.path.split('/').last;

      FormData data = FormData.fromMap({
         "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile(
           file.path,
           filename: fileName,
         ),
      });

     Dio dio = new Dio();

     dio.post("http://192.168.43.225/api/media", data: data)
     .then((response) => print(response))
     .catchError((error) => print(error));
   }
   ```
3. On the server side, I am using `Laravel` [Laravel](https://laravel.com/), I handle the request as follow

   ```
   public function store(Request $request)
   {
       $file = $request->file('file');

       $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

       $fullFileName = time(). '.'. $extension;
       $file->storeAs('uploads', $fullFileName,  ['disk' => 'local']);

       return 'uploaded Successfully';
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasted around 4 hours to get this work done. Finally, I solved it with your answer by reducing the image size. +1 for you.

Comment: I am really glad it was helpful.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Comment: Set image size to 1024 and quality to 0 (lowest) for small good looking images.

Answer (score 19):

In the latest version of **Dio** :

It should look like this.

```
String fileName = imageFile.path.split('/').last;
FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
  "image-param-name": await MultipartFile.fromFile(
    imageFile.path,
    filename: fileName,
    contentType: new MediaType("image", "jpeg"), //important
  ),
});
```

If without this line.

```
contentType: new MediaType("image", "jpeg")
```

Maybe it will cause an error: `DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [400] Exception`

And get `MediaType` in this package: [http_parser](https://pub.dev/packages/http_parser)

Comment: I tried without `contentType` therefore backend server unable to process the file. According to your answer, just providing `contentType` resolved my problem.

Comment: Thank very much!
Some server will unknow file type if we don't explicit declaration this type

Comment: Thanks, I was trying without media type and wasted lot of time. Acrrording to your answer i provided media type, and my issue resolved.

Comment: Thank you very much only this worked for me after try hours...

Answer (score 8):

The following code uploads multiple image files from a dio client to a golang server.

1. dioclient.dart

> ```
>  FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
>    "name": "wendux",
>    "age": 25,
>    "other" : "params",
>  });
>  for (File item in yourFileList)
>    formData.files.addAll([
>      MapEntry("image_files", await MultipartFile.fromFile(item.path)),
>    ]);
>  Dio dio = new Dio()..options.baseUrl = "http://serverURL:port";
>  dio.post("/uploadFile", data: formData).then((response) {
>    print(response);
>  }).catchError((error) => print(error));
> ```

2. golangServer.go

> ```
> package main
> import (
>     "fmt"
>     "io"
>     "net/http"
>     "os"
> )
> func uploadFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
>     err := r.ParseMultipartForm(200000)
>     if err != nil {
>         fmt.Fprintln(w, err)
>         return
>     }
>     formdata := r.MultipartForm
>     files := formdata.File["image_files"]
>     for i, _ := range files {
>         file, err := files[i].Open()
>         defer file.Close()
>         if err != nil {
>             fmt.Fprintln(w, err)
>             return
>         }
>         out, err := os.Create("/path/to/dir/" + files[i].Filename)
>         defer out.Close()
>         if err != nil {
>             fmt.Fprintf(w, "Unable to create the file for writing. Check your write access privilege")
>             return
>         }
>         _, err = io.Copy(out, file)
>         if err != nil {
>             fmt.Fprintln(w, err)
>             return
>         }
>         fmt.Fprintf(w, "Files uploaded successfully : ")
>         fmt.Fprintf(w, files[i].Filename+"\n")
>     }
> }
> func startServer() {
>     http.HandleFunc("/uploadFile", uploadFile)
>     http.ListenAndServe(":9983", nil)
> }
> func main() {
>     fmt.Println("Server starts!")
>     startServer()
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution, where I am uploading file a specific directory which is generated different camera package which requires file path to save jpg file in the provided path.

and I was fetching file name with path and passing to

```
  DIO package
```

which was giving file length issue, to I have implemented below steps to solve the issue

get File Name With Full Path from directory
create a File from the Path

```
File(directoryFilePathWithExtension);
```

and pass File.path to the dio package

```
MultipartFile.fromFile(
    File(directoryFilePathWithExtension).path,
    filename: DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UploadFileInfo.fromBytes` if you're working with memory images (The error message above shows that your file is invalid and doesn't exist).

Comment: sorry,can you tell me what memory images ? i dont know about this

Comment: When you're uploading image from gallery, you can't access the image directly (because you're building your app for two different platforms Android and IOS), so it's better to work with the file bytes not the file path.

For your case, try using ```UploadFileInfo.fromBytes(_image.readAsBytes(), 'image.png');```

Comment: I'm using ` "image": UploadFileInfo.fromBytes(utf8.encode("Hellow Word"), '$_image')` , i'm get `message "Http status error [404]" ` ```DioErrorType (DioErrorType.RESPONSE)```

Comment: 404 Status Code is  ```Page Not Found```, so please check your link first and then try again.

Comment: If i'm using ` "image": UploadFileInfo.fromBytes(_image.readAsBytes(), 'image.png')`  give me error ```The argument type 'Future<List<int>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<int>'``` . But if i'm write ```"image": UploadFileInfo.fromBytes(_image.readAsBytesSync(), 'image.png')``` error disappear. It's Different using `readAsBytes` and `readAsBytesSync` ?

Comment: Use this: 
```UploadFileInfo.fromBytes(await _image.readAsBytes(), 'image.png')```

Comment: give me `error :null message :"Http status error [404]" ` but i'm sure my Url API is correct. what's mean `"Http status error [404]"` this ?

Comment: sure, i'm already test in Postman, on top description i'm edit. it's works. i'm suspicious the image not found on app

Comment: If you comment sending the image, is this problem still exist?

Comment: If i,m just sending textcontroller not error,but if i'm include image error show.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there are many issue in file upload

1. try in android Api 21 because it did not have android permissions if api is working in android api 21 then it wil also work on above versions.
2. you might not able to get the file in above android version
3. you just need

FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
      "av_document": await MultipartFile.fromFile(_filePath,filename: 
       _fileName),
         });

to upload any file or image to server and one more thing to note

```
        _filePaths = await FilePicker.getMultiFilePath(type: _pickingType, 
        fileExtension: _extension);


        _fileName = _filePath.split('/').last
```

by using this process u can upload file or image to server

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I am using
[dio: ^4.0.6](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) (for uploading)
[flutter_native_image: ^0.0.6+1](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_image) (for reducing image size)

to reduce file size

```
  File? compressedFile = profileImage.value == null
      ? null
      : await FlutterNativeImage.compressImage(
          profileImage.value?.path ?? '',
          quality: 20,
          percentage: 60);
```

dio formData map

```
var formData = dio.FormData.fromMap({
    "name": input['name']!.text,
    "profile_pic": await dio.MultipartFile.fromFile(compressedFile.path),
    "birth_date": input['dob']!.text,})
```

request ->

```
response = await _dio.post(url, data: formData);
```