# Uploading an image in flutter to rest api

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to upload an image in flutter using dio package but it doesn't work and I've tested the api using postman and it worked the image got uploaded any idea how to make it work.

This is a code snippet of my upload function

```
   void editMyProfile({
    String? username,
    String? birthdate,
    dynamic photo,
  }) async {
    emit(EditMyProfileLoadingState());
    try {
      await DioHelper.patchData(
        token: "Token $token",
        url: "$profileEndPoint$userId/",
        data: {
          "name": username,
          "date_of_birth": birthdate,
          "photo": photo,
        },
      );
      profileName = username!;
      profileBirthdate = birthdate!;
      showToast(
          text: "Profile updated successfully", state: ToastStates.success);
      emit(EditMyProfileSuccessState());
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      if (e.response == null) return;
      print(e.response!.data);
      emit(EditMyProfileErrorState());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Binary or base64? If it's binary you should use multipart.

Comment: I tried but still didn't work

Comment: try this answer [flutter-dio-how-to-upload-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57509972/flutter-dio-how-to-upload-image)

Comment: Thanks man it worked I tried it before but in a wrong way, thanks again for helping.